# Terraform: Unable to launch ECS Fargate launchType

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, terraform, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I'm trying to launch an ECS cluster with Fargate Tasks.

Here's my Terraform resource

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "ecs-zoo" {
family                = "${var.project}"
container_definitions = "${data.template_file.ecs-zookeeper.rendered}"
network_mode          = "awsvpc"
cpu = 512
memory = 1024
requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
}
```

And here's my task definition

```
[
{
    "name": "zoo",
    "image": "${zoo_image}",
    "essential": true,
    "portMappings": [
        {
            "containerPort": ${zook_port},
            "hostPort": ${zook_port}
        }
    ],
    "environment": [
        {
            "name": "ZOO_SERVERS",
            "value": "${zook-servers}"
        }
    
    ]
}
]
```

Here is the service resource

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "ecs-zoo" {
name = "${var.project}${count.index+1}"
cluster         = "${aws_ecs_cluster.ecs.id}"
task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.ecs-zoo.arn}"
enable_ecs_managed_tags = true
desired_count = 1
propagate_tags = "SERVICE"

deployment_minimum_healthy_percent = 100
deployment_maximum_percent         = 400
network_configuration {
  subnets          = "${var.vpc_subnets}"
  security_groups  = ["${aws_security_group.ecs.id}"]
  assign_public_ip = false
}
service_registries {
registry_arn   = "${aws_service_discovery_service.discovery_service-zoo.*.arn[count.index]}"
}

lifecycle {
  create_before_destroy = true
}
count = "${var.zoo-instance-number}" 
}
```

The problem is that it only launches EC2 tasks and not FARGATE as you can see in the snapshot.
[image: snapshot]

If I check the task definition in the console it says this
[image: snapshot 2]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you launching the task? What you have included in your question just creates a task definition, it doesn't launch a task.

Comment: @MarkB I've added the service defintion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify `launch_type = "FARGATE"` in the service definition.

Comment: omg...don't know why the task definitions have those compatibilities thingy anyway. Thank you so much.